# Futures to send concurrent HTTP GET requests

Tags: scala, concurrency, future, resource-leak

Suppose I am writing a function to send a few concurrent HTTP GET requests and wait for all the responses with a time-out. If at least one response does not have status `200` or does not come within the time-out my function should return failure.

I am writing this function `tryGets` like this:

```
import java.net.URL

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContext, Future}
import scala.util.Try

def unsafeGet(url: URL): String = {
  val in = url.openStream()
  scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(in).mkString
}

def futureGet(url: URL)
             (implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[String] = Future {
  unsafeGet(url)
}

def tryGets(urls: Seq[URL], timeOut: Duration)
            (implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Try[Seq[String]] = Try {
  val fut = Future.sequence(urls.map(futureGet))
  Await.result(fut, timeOut)
}
```

Does it make sense ? 
Does not it leak future instances in case of time-out ?

Comment: did you look into for comprehensions? Here is a good article about how to use it: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/09/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-8-welcome-to-the-future.html

Comment: for-comprehension executes futures sequentially rather than concurrently.

Comment: Not if you declare them ahead of time.
So you can do val x = Future{}; for{result <- x}
Instead of for{result <- Future{}}

Comment: here is a good explanation: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-use-multiple-scala-futures-in-for-comprehension-loop

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Once I instantiate futures before for-comprehension they run concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

If one of the Future's time out, then the rest of the Future's will continue to execute because the future's are eager and will continue to run on the Execution Context. What you could do is fold over the Urls but this will execute them in serial.

```
urls.foldleft(Future.sucessful(Seq.empty)) { (future, url) =>
  future.flatMap(accum => futureGet(url).map(accum :+ _))
}
```